# Typescript/ Angular - How can I rename object received from server?

Tags: angular, typescript, server, interface

I am getting data from service in the following format

yourData.ts file

```
export interface YourData {
    first_name: number;
    last_name: number;
```

On the UI Angular I would like to display the format to `Lower camel case`

html file

```
firstName is {{firstName}}
lastName is {{lastName}}
```

Where and how can I make the above change?

I was planning of something like, not sure if thats right

```
export const parseFromServer = (response:any) =>{
    return {
        firstName : response.first_name
    }
}
```

Comment: You can directly write in that case, can't you? I mean, like firstName is {{yourObject.first_name}} in your HTML.

Comment: @Deepak what I want is to rename `first_name` as `firstName`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

If you wish to make use of the same object, the approach is to add a new key and delete the old key. Please check the old answer if you wish to make use of a new object.

```js
    var oldObject: any = {
        first_name: 1,
        last_name: 2
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(oldObject);
    for(var key in oldObject) 
    {
        let words = key.split("_");
        oldObject[words[0][0].toLowerCase() + words[0].substring(1) + words[1][0].toUpperCase() + words[1].substring(1)] = oldObject[key]; // add new key
        delete oldObject[key]; // delete old key
    }
    console.log(oldObject)
```

All you need to do is just make sure there the key names are unique and the word format is {word1}_{word2}

**OLD ANSWER:**

From the comment, I understand you wish to rename your object keys from something like `first_name` to `firstName`. You cannot rename as such, but you can create a new object with the desired key names and assign the appropriate values.

From your example, if you know the key names already, then it is straightforward:

```js
var oldObject = {
    first_name: 1,
    last_name: 2
}
var newObject = {
  firstName: oldObject.first_name,
  lastName: oldObject.last_name
}; 
console.log(newObject)
```

If you don't know the key names, but you know the format is {word1}_{word2}, then you can write your own logic. Here's one:

```js
var oldObject: any = {
    first_name: 1,
    last_name: 2
}
var newObject: any = {};
var keys = Object.keys(oldObject);
for(var key in oldObject) 
{
  let words = key.split("_");
  newObject[words[0][0].toLowerCase() + words[0].substring(1) + words[1][0].toUpperCase() + words[1].substring(1)] = oldObject[key];
}
console.log(newObject)
```

Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBA9gNgJgeQEYCsCmBjALgLgiAOwE8IBeCAbwCgJaIAzASzAGcsB9AkAWzTwEYANDTowQbTjz4QATFQC%20VUJAJoA7snTY8hEuQryA3EvAQA1miIsyETZiwA6C1YAUsRKnsBKY-ShgXZXNLCEYCaHg7bC8IKmpaGDQsCDV-OGtyZwcWAAcYRiwXACJ2Ip8RVQ1PbABtVLB0moAGAF1mlocsKAAZKDU0MABhcTQXGIBqFLSWduyAVyQ2MDCAcxd%20CamGmf421s6oAFUcnIHhllHN%20sbd%20cWsZYI1jZabdyisGucW40UMKAILFgaAcMCga0qHy8VCAA).

Comment: Hi deepak, thanks for the answer. Can you help me out  as to how can I rename in interface and then send to UI?

Comment: Sure. If you do not want a new object but to simply rename the same object, check the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, did you update your above code? I think its still same

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this approach, not sure if it will work in your case - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/spreading-resting-and-renaming-properties-in-typescript-68fb35ffb1f

Comment: I tried this `const parseFromServer = ({first_name, ...remainder})=>({firstName:first_name, ...remainder})` it is giving error  `Binding element 'first_name' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)`